# Cannot commit on SVN on windows

Tags: tortoisesvn

I have a fresh project on SVN from SourceForge, I can checkout and update, but when I try to commit I get this error :

[image]

How can I get this to work ? My friend is on Linux and was able to commit/update/checkout just fine.

Comment: this [Server fault](http://serverfault.com/questions/114852/cannot-commit-to-svn-repository-via-http) post might help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works now, I just deleted my authentication data and it prompted me for my credentials and it worked.

I was probably already logged in with another username.

[image]